# 5V vs. 3V diode protection circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, diodes

I'm using USB cables in an very unconventional way (don't ask, we had a barrel full of USB cables left over from something else) to connect between boards with 3v battery power and also not following the USB pinout at all.

And would like to place diodes behind the USB receptacle to prevent anything bad happening if someone were to be actually try plugging one into a computer.

Someone suggested this configuration, and my mental model of how diodes should work with separate voltage sources isn't strong enough to figure out how this would work, but I'm also not convinced this circuit looks right. What would actually happen if this were connected?

[image]

Comment: If you did this as drawn, you'd blow both your diodes and possibly your USB port.

Comment: 5-3=2V across 2 diodes serves what purpose !?